# How do I change the time zone in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How can I change the time zone in CakePHP? My application uses the Indian time zone but it is hosted on a US server which takes a US time zone. Can anyone tell me how I can change the time zone?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US?!?!?!?!

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH CRAZY

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 9):

You can set the time zone in /app/config/core.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('YourTimeZone')    //php5.3 is required
```

edit:
    try add this in your app/config/bootstrap.php

```
putenv('TZ=YourTimeZone');
```

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata') specifically for Indian Time Zone

Comment: Place this code in Config/bootstrap.php (Cakephp 2.6+)

Answer (score 2):

Set timezone in app/config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'Europe/Paris')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set timezone in App/Config/bootstrap.php (Cakephp 2.6+)

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');